# How can I get the current subsection title font size?

Tags: fontsize, subsection

I'm want to get the font size of a subsection title to use it manually in other parts of the same document as a title using `\textbf`.  How can I do it?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: using explicit font sizes and textbf in a document should be a non-aim. why not use `\subsection*{text}` ?

Comment: I'm using memoir, @Mico.

Comment: Fair enough @DavidCarlisle, I'll follow your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to have

```
\documentclass{article} 
\show\subsection
```

which gives:

```
> \subsection=\long macro:
->\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@ }{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex 
\@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \large \bfseries }.
```

`\@startsection` is a complicated macro, so we'll ignore parameters 2, 3, 4, and 5, but it appears that the size is in parameter 6 as `\large`.